# Istio Ingress with cert-manager

Tags: ssl, istio, cert-manager, pass-through

I have Kubernetes with Kafka where is also running Istio with Strimzi. Certificates are stored in cert-manager. I want to use TLS passthrough in my ingress but I am a little bit confused of that.

When `SIMPLE` is used, there is `credentialName`, which must be the same as secret.

```
tls:
  mode: SIMPLE
  credentialName: httpbin-credential
```

It is nice and simple way. But how about `mode: PASSTHROUGH` when I have many hosts? I studied demo on istio web (https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-sni-passthrough/#deploy-an-nginx-server) and their certificate details are stored in server configuration file and they are creating `configmap`. In official Istio documentation is noted that this parameter is only for `MUTUAL` and `SIMPLE`.

What is correct and simple way to expose my hosts using istio ingress to external traffic using cert-manager?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes and Istio are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between SIMPLE & PASSTHROUGH is:

- SIMPLE TLS instructs the gateway to pass the ingress traffic by terminating TLS.
- PASSTHROUGH TLS instructs the gateway to pass the ingress traffic AS IS, without terminating TLS.